# runtime error (NZEC) in Java

Tags: java

I wrote a Java code to generate prime numbers between two integers. I get a runtime error (NZEC) in SPOJ. How can I fix this?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
public class prime {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
        Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
        int m =  x.nextInt();
        int n =  y.nextInt();
        if (m >= 1 && n <= 1000000000 && n - m <= 100000) {
            for (int current = m; current <= n; current++) {
                int sqr_root = (int) Math.sqrt(current);
                boolean is_prime = true;
                for (int i = 2; i <= sqr_root; i++) {
                    if (current % i == 0) {
                            is_prime = false; // Current is not prime.
                    }
                }
                if (is_prime) {
                        System.out.println(current);
                }
            }
        }
        return; 
    }
}
```

Comment: What on earth are *NZEC* and *SPOJ*? And where exactly do you get the error?

Comment: NZEC (non-zero exit code) - this message means that the program exited returning a value different from 0 to the shell. For languages such as C, this probably means you forgot to add "return 0" at the end of the program. For interpreted languages (including JAVA) NZEC will usually mean that your program either crashed or raised an uncaught exception.

Comment: SPOJ (Sphere Online Judge) is an online judge system with over 200,000 registered users and over 20000 problems. The solution to problems can be submitted in over 40 languages. SPOJ has a rapidly growing problem set/tasks available for practice 24 hours/day, including many original tasks prepared by the community of expert problem setters associated with the project. SPOJ allows advanced users to organize contests under their own rules and problems. It also includes a forum where programmers can discuss how they can solve a particular problem.

Comment: HackerEarth error codes !

Comment: Since your code doesn't ever *try* to terminate with a non-zero exit code, it must do so as the result of an uncaught exception. If you want help, you'll need to run your code from the command-line, or from Eclipse, and tell us what exception you get, and where it occurs.

Comment: When I run the code in eclipse, I do not get any error or exception in the code. It runs fine.

Comment: @abhishekKanodia Please do try to format your code next time - what you had pasted probably wouldn't even compile. Formatting your question appropriately gives us some indication that you care.

Comment: @Whymarrh I will definitely keep that in mind from next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

The stand-out error is that you've created two `Scanner`s to read from `System.in`. I suspect this will cause an exception; certainly it's ill-advised.

Change this

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
Scanner y = new Scanner(System.in);
int m =  x.nextInt();
int n =  y.nextInt();
```

to this

```
Scanner x = new Scanner(System.in);
int m =  x.nextInt();
int n =  x.nextInt();
```

This is assuming, of course, that you really do want to take your values from standard input rather than as command-line arguments.

(And you can get rid of the `return` from your `main` method.)

Comment: I get a null pointer exception in the line int m = x.nextInt().

Comment: @abhishekKanodia Then I can only assume you're not providing any input to the program. Are you sure you want to read from standard input, rather than taking arguments on the command line? It would be odd for a program that needed exactly two inputs to read them from standard input.

Comment: I want to take two user inputs and display all the prime numbers between them. Also I want to do this for 10 test cases.