# Why isn't this code working? FCTRL2

Tags: java

I have recently shifted from C to Java in competitive programming. But any solution which I submit shows me NZEC runtime error. One such question is https://www.codechef.com/problems/FCTRL2
and my solution is

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.math.BigInteger;

class Solution{
    public int t, i=0;
    public BigInteger N;
    public static void main(String args[]){
        Solution sol = new Solution();
        sol.scanT();
        sol.testCase();
        System.exit(0);
    }

    public void scanT(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        t = sc.nextInt();
        if(t>100 || t<1){
            return;
        }
    }

    public void testCase(){
        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
        for(i=0; i<t; i++){
           N = sc.nextBigInteger();
           if(N.compareTo(BigInteger.ONE)<0 || N.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(100))>0){
               return;
           }
           BigInteger z =  factorial();
           System.out.println(z);
        }

    }

    public BigInteger factorial(){
      BigInteger Fact = N;
      while(N.compareTo(BigInteger.valueOf(2))>0){
          Fact = Fact.multiply(N.subtract(BigInteger.ONE));
          N = N.subtract(BigInteger.ONE);
      }
   return Fact;
    }
}
```

Kindly help me find the error in my solution which results in Runtime error NZEC everytime. My solution shows correct output when run on my computer.

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: not sure what the problem is but ,why are you creating multiple scanners?

Comment: Try creating only one Scanner

Comment: I dont think that will help much

Comment: Why don't you try that

Comment: well i tried that...its not working.. here's the code http://ideone.com/R1T6Gs

Comment: Did you provide inputs to your program?

Comment: yeah i have tried giving inputs too...it is running on my pc...but showing runtime error on codechef, spoj and ideone

Comment: Its working for me http://ideone.com/LoY10o

Comment: the code which i pasted didnt gave correct output for 99 as input..i think we need biginteger for that..i have changed the code to biginteger...now this gives correct output on my pc...even for 99..but shows Runtime error..
http://ideone.com/ihNoiO

Comment: In your latest code, use only one Scanner and it'll work

Comment: oh yes it worked...thanks...why was it not working?

Comment: Read this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/26293709/runtime-error-nzec-in-java

Comment: 1)You had multiple scanners  2)used int which cannot hold the result for large numbers

Answer (score 1):

The NZEC error is generated due to multiple Scanner objects using System.in simultaneously.
Using only one Scanner object solves the problem of Runtime Error NZEC.